# Accessing URL variables in Django 1.5 class-based view

Tags: python, django

I'm migrating a project from Django 1.2 to Django 1.5. The project used function-based views such as this:

```
def notecard_product(request, stockcode):
    if request.user.is_authenticated(): 
        liked = Recommendation.objects.values_list('product_id',flat=True).filter(recommended=True, user=request.user)
        unliked = Recommendation.objects.values_list('product_id',flat=True).filter(recommended=False, user=request.user)
        extra_context = {"liked" : liked, "unliked":unliked}
    else:
        extra_context = {"liked" : [0], "unliked": [0]}
    return object_detail(request, queryset=Product.objects.live(),
                         object_id=stockcode,
                         extra_context=extra_context,
                         template_name='products/notecard.html', template_object_name='notecard_product')`enter code here`
```

In this excerpt, `stockcode` is captured from the URL and used to determine `object_id`. So I'm wondering how I would do this in a class-based view. This is what I have so far:

```
class NotecardProductListView(ListView):
    queryset=Product.objects.live()
    pk=self.kwargs['stockcode']
    template_name='products/notecard.html'
    context_object_name='notecard_product'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BooksListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated(): 
            liked = Recommendation.objects.values_list('product_id',flat=True).filter(recommended=True, user=self.request.user)
            unliked = Recommendation.objects.values_list('product_id',flat=True).filter(recommended=False, user=self.request.user)
            extra_context = {"liked" : liked, "unliked":unliked}
        else:
            extra_context = {"liked" : [0], "unliked": [0]}
        context.update(extra_context)
        return context
```

`pk` is the new name for the old `object_id` kwarg. Obviously, this code doesn't work, because I can't access `self` outside of a function. But I'm not really sure how to do this. I need to set `pk` to something in the keyword arguments, but can't find a way to do this, as `pk` needs to be set in the class body outside of any functions. I also don't really have a way to experiment and try things, because the entire project is broken right now due to deprecated function calls.

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you need to use this `pk` value in your new view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that `pk` is the new name for `object_id`, nor why you think that you need to set it to a value per request. The point of the class-level attributes in class-based views is that they are set per view class, not per instance: they refer to the place the view will go to look up the value, not the actual value itself.

Your first mistake is that the equivalent of the old `object-detail` view is, not surprisingly, `DetailView`, not `ListView`. As the documentation shows, ListView gets the ability to show an object detail via its inheritance from the [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin). That mixin expects a class-level attribute called `pk_url_kwarg`, which is the name of the argument captured from the URL which identifies the object's PK: in your case, this is the *string* `'stockcode'`. The instance itself takes care of looking up that value in any particular request, you don't need to do it.

Comment: Thanks very much. I confused object_list with object_detail, so that was one of my issues. And I was being really stupid about class attributes for some reason.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/) is where I got confused about the `pk` variable. Actually, I'm still a little bit confused. Quote: "The `object_id` argument to the `object_detail` view has been renamed `pk` on the `DetailView`."

So what you're saying, though, is that I should just set `pk_url_kwarg='stockcode'` and not worry about `pk` or `object-id`?

Comment: I think that's just bad wording. As the SingleObjectMixin docs show, "By default, pk_url_kwarg is 'pk'." - so the migration doc was confusing the value of the argument with the name of the attribute. But yes, you should just do as you describe.

Comment: Okay, good. I think I'm just making some things way too complicated. Class-based generic views do make a lot of sense, but I wish the migration docs were a little bit more detailed. Thanks though, you've been super helpful!